# Запуск и мониторинг openFortiVPN в терминале

Tags: linux, vpn

Установил **openfortivpn**
Прописал обычный конфиг `/etc/openfortivpn/my-config`:

```
host = ...
port = ...
username = ...
password = ...
trusted-cert = ...
persistent = 1
```

Далее запускаю так:
`sudo openfortivpn -c /etc/openfortivpn/my-config`
В итоге всё работает.

В данный момент при запуске блокируется терминал, вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В принципе это не проблема. Я данное окно терминала могу свернуть и открыть другое, если надо. А потом когда надо отключиться, я просто жму в данном терминале **Ctrl+C** и VPN соединение уничтожается.

(1) Но всё же хочу уточнить, **а можно ли как-то так запустить, чтобы соединение было в "фоне", и не блокировало терминал?**

(2) Ну и соответственно сразу возникает другой вопрос: **а можно ли как-то посмотреть статус соединения? Есть такая команда?** Чтобы понять, в данный момент есть подключение по VPN или нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ screen
$ sudo openfortivpn -c /etc/openfortivpn/my-config
```

Для отключения: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>, потом <kbd>d</kbd>

Для возврата:

```
$ screen -r
```